# Kotlin cross-compilation for multiple targets in single build run

Tags: kotlin, cross-compiling, kotlin-native

Default Kotlin native project gradle configuration looks like:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.10"
}
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    nativeTarget.apply {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}
```

Such configuration can produce binaries only for single target. How can be the configuration adjusted so that **single build will produce 3 binary for all mentioned targets**: Windows, Linux and MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

You can just set a number of targets, and then running the `assemble` task will produce binaries for all available on your host machine. It is important because one cannot create a binary for macOS anywhere but on macOS host, Windows target also has some complex preparations(see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43024)). Also, there could be some problem with source sets - if their contents are identical, maybe it worth connecting them as in the example below:

```
kotlin {
    macosX64("nativeMac")
    linuxX64("nativeLin")
    mingwX64("nativeWin")

     targets.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget> {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val nativeMacMain by getting //let's assume that you work on Mac and so put all the code here
        val nativeLinMain by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMacMain)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to cross compile if there is a dependency on a C library via `cinterop`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `build.gradle.kts` that configures Gradle to build a Kotlin Multiplatform project with arm64 and x86-64 targets on Linux, arm64 and x86-64 targets on macOS, and a single x86-64 (mingw) target on Windows.

```kotlin
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.9.21"
    kotlin("multiplatform") version kotlinVersion
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    // Initialize all target platforms.
    // Incompatible targets will be automatically skipped with a warning;
    // we suppress such warnings by adding a line to gradle.properties:
    // kotlin.native.ignoreDisabledTargets=true
    val linuxArm64 = linuxArm64()
    val linuxX64 = linuxX64()
    val macosArm64 = macosArm64()
    val macosX64 = macosX64()
    val windows = mingwX64("windows")

    // Configure which native targets to build, based on current platform.
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val nativeTargets = when {
        hostOs == "Linux" -> listOf(linuxArm64, linuxX64)
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> listOf(macosArm64, macosX64)
        hostOs.startsWith("Windows") -> listOf(windows)
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    // Define dependencies between source sets.
    // We declare an intermediate source set called posix, which
    // the Linux and macOS sources extend, but Windows does not.
    // For further details, see:
    // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-advanced-project-structure.html#declaring-custom-source-sets
    sourceSets {
        val posixMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain.get())
        }
        val macosArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(posixMain)
        }
        val macosX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(posixMain)
        }
        val linuxArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(posixMain)
        }
        val linuxX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(posixMain)
        }
    }

    // Build the binaries for all activated native targets.
    nativeTargets.forEach {
        it.apply {
            binaries {
                executable {
                    entryPoint = "main"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It assumes the following directory structure for sources:

```
src
├── commonMain
│   ├── kotlin
├── linuxArm64Main
│   └── kotlin
├── linuxX64Main
│   └── kotlin
├── macosArm64Main
│   └── kotlin
├── macosX64Main
│   └── kotlin
├── posixMain
│   └── kotlin
└── windowsMain
    └── kotlin
```

where `src/posixMain/kotlin` is an area to put intermediate sources consumed by both Linux and macOS targets; I find is useful since Kotlin Native's `platform.posix` library functions largely identically across those two platforms. (In my experience, `platform.posix` is also very close when used with mingw, but there are more differences that can be problematic, so I like to implement my Windows-specific code using the `platform.windows` library instead.)

I don't have an answer for cross-compiling *all* platforms at once, since as Artyom Degtyarev mentioned, there are extra challenges with that. But you can cross-compile CPU architecture using a structure like the above, building both arm64 and x86-64 for Linux and macOS, which allows to target more platforms using a CI pipeline such as [GitHub Actions with an x86-64-only matrix configuration](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs), and then assemble the final binaries into a single output artifact at the end.